# C: trouble statically linking binary that uses openssl AES-256 encryption

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to produce a static binary that can be run on generic linux machine (same machine architecture, same bitnes, same endienness and compatible kernel system call interface). When I pass -static to gcc I get the following warning:

```
# gcc -static testme.c -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lltdl -static-libgcc
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-slackware-linux/4.8.2/../../../libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
dso_dlfcn.c:(.text+0x21): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
#
```

Although the binary runs some systems I've tried it on I suppose the warning means my static binary will not run on a system with different glibc version.

I included -ldl and -lltdl along the other libs to be linked, in an attempt to eliminate the warning, but still get the same. What am I doing wrong ? and how can I get rid of the warning ?

The actual code can be seen on the [obash testing branch](https://github.com/louigi600/obash/tree/testing) on github.
once you produce obash it should then be used to produce a reusable static binary by calling it with "-r" flag.

Since it's openssl that pulls dlopen into the equation is there an alternative way of doing acceptably safe symmetric encrypting that will not use dlopen and be safe to use even when statically linked ?

Comment: Why do you think a static binary "can be run on any generic linux machine"?  Linux doesn't have a standardized system call interface into the kernel.  That's what the `libc` interface is for.

Comment: What is a "generic Linux machine"? Which Architecture? Which Linux version? What is "bitnes"? You mean Endianess? That would be the least of your problems. And if that is a static binary, why would it depend on the installed glibc? Or still dynamically load a shared library?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Worse: different CPUs have different instruction sets.

Comment: Ok It will not run on machines with different bitness and kernels too far appart ... but supposing the kernel's system call interfaces are compatible and supposing the machine are both 64bit (or both 32 bit) can I get it to run if glibc is a different version ?
BTW I edited the question making it clearer the scope of the machines it should run on

Comment: @Olaf : I'm not trying to compile on x86 and run on a totally different architecture (like ARM) ...

Comment: So what do you consider "generic Linux" then? That would be the first thing to think about before asking. Without clear definitions, you should not start such projects.

Comment: @Olaf: as I said in a comment above I edited the scope of that in the question ... now it should be clear where I expect to be able to run it.
In any case the question is al about how to get rid of the warning ?  and is there something I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: @Olaf "Bitness" probably refers to 32-bit vs 64-bit.

Comment: @AndrewHenle On the other hand syscall interface is extremely stable.

Comment: Yes .... I'll add to that also same endianness just to make sure someone comes up with some architectures supporting both big and little endienness.

Comment: @yugr "Extremly stable" compared to what?  Nevermind the fact that the question requires use of dynamic linking via `dlopen()`.  Using dynamic linking ties the application to the operating system's run-time shared objects no matter how it's linked - it's a fundamental contradiction for such an executable to be statically linked.  "How do I dehydrate my water?"

Comment: @yugr Intresting not totally duplicate but possible the same root cause. So it's not possible to get rid of the warning  and I'm not doing anything wrong: it's just the way it is ?

Comment: It's openssl that pulls dlopen into the code .... if I do rc4 encoding can I get rid of the problem ?

Comment: Afaik, RC4 is considered cracked, and should not be used anymore.

Comment: @yugr: can you please remove the possible duplicate answer ?
dlopen was pulled in by openssl so I can't fix/workaround like suggested.
RC4 is unadvisable as alternative so still looking for something I can do to work around the problem if possible.

Comment: @louigi600 Well, the duplicate answer says that calling `dlopen` from statically linked executable is only possible on the same distro, with same library versions. In other cases it'll fail. So it sounds like it answers your question (the answer being "no, you can't call `dlopen` from statically linked executable").

Comment: @AndrewHenle "it's a fundamental contradiction for such an executable to be statically linked" - yeah, it's more of a hack but Glibc manages to work in some circumstances. Dietlibc and musl do not allow this though.

Comment: since it's openssl that pulls dlopen into the equation is there an alternative way of doing safe symmetric encrypting that will not do that and be safe to use even when statically linked ?

Comment: @AndrewHenle "Extremly stable compared to what?" - executable that's statically linked against some reasonably old Glibc (which does not use new syscalls) will most likely work on all modern kernels (see this [infamous piece](https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/12/23/75) for example).

Comment: Ok I reformulated the question so that it's not a duplicate